# How do I fix the linker error?

Tags: c++, linker, binary, decimal

In function `main':

[Linker error] undefined reference to`Binary_to_Decimal()'
  [Linker error] undefined reference to `Decimal_to_Binary()'
Working on decimal to binary and binary to decimal program. 
Unfortunately I ran into the compiling errors I lack knowledge to fix. 
I would greatly appreciate the help to fix and learn about the issue.
Here is the source code of the program.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
#include <bitset> 
void Binary_to_Decimal(); 
void Decimal_to_Binary(); 


int main (int argv, char argc) { 
      while(1<2){
      int m_Choice; 
      std::cout << "Enter 1 - for Binary to Decimal" << std::endl; 
      std::cout << "Enter 2 - for Decimal to Binary" << std::endl; 
      std::cin >> m_Choice;
      if (m_Choice == 1) { 
                   Binary_to_Decimal(); 
                   }else if (m_Choice == 2) { 
                        Decimal_to_Binary();  
                         } 



     return 0; 
     } 
}       
void Binary_To_Decimal(){ 
     std::string Binary_to_Decimal_cstr;
     std::cout << "Please enter binary number: " << std::endl; 
     std::cin>>Binary_to_Decimal_cstr; 
     std::cout<<Binary_to_Decimal_cstr; 
     std::cout <<"converted to Decimal is:" << std::bitset<32>(Binary_to_Decimal_cstr).to_ulong(); 
     std::cout << std::endl; 
     } 

void  Decimal_To_Binary(){ 


        int Decimal_to_Binary_Var; 
        std::cout << "Please enter  Decimal number: " << std::endl; 
        std::cin >> Decimal_to_Binary_Var; 
        std::cout << Decimal_to_Binary_Var;
        std::cout << "converted to Binary is: " << std::bitset<32>(Decimal_to_Binary_Var); 
        std::cout << std::endl;  
        }
```

Comment: Function names are **case sensitive**.

Comment: Try `while(m_Choice!=0)` then when you're done testing press 0 to exit, save yourself from some funky habits.

Answer (score 1):

Case sensitive problem!

```
void Binary_to_Decimal();  --> void Binary_To_Decimal(); 
            ^                              ^


void Decimal_to_Binary();  --> void Decimal_To_Binary(); 
             ^                              ^
```

Compiler searches for `void Binary_to_Decimal()` but you implelemted `void Binary_To_Decimal();` which is different thing.

Answer (score 1):

You call `Binary_to_Decimal` but the function is called `Binary_To_Decimal`. Notice the small versus capital letters in the `To` part. Same thing with the other function.

All languages based on C (like C++) are case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

You named your functions `Decimal_To_Binary` and `Binary_To_Decimal` but you call them with the "t" lowercased, thus the compiler don't know which functions you are calling.

The name must match exactly, and it's case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

The Function you are calling is "Binary_to_Decimal" but the function implemented in "Decimal_To_Binary()" {Names are not exactly same} ... same with case "Decimal_to_Binary".

Comment: Thank you all for the replies.You have been great help :)